# Is there a way to run my user defined function without updating any input parameters in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have had this issue pop up on a handful of occasions, and I want to know if there is a fix for it. Here is a simple function that will return the entire column of data in an excel sheet. It works when I use the function in the sheet. However, when I add any additional row after I have used the function, the function will not "spill" the additional row because it was not dependent on that cell I added.

```vb
Public Function ToLastRow(Reference As Range) As Variant

ToLastRow = Range(Reference, Reference.End(xlDown))

End Function
```

I know I could fix the issue by adding an additional parameter that references a count of the rows in the column, and this would then call the function with new added rows, but I would like it if there was a way to set the dependency for the function manually (apart from the parameters of the function).

Comment: Can you not press `F2` in the first cell and press `ENTER` key and the formula will update using the new rows??

Comment: Or you can add `Application.Volatile` before `ToLastRow = Range(Reference, Reference.End(xlDown))` and the formula will auto update

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "to set the dependency for the function manually". Excel calls the function only if its arguments change. But you can provide the function with the range which covers all the region to track as the dummy argument:

```
Public Function ToLastRow(Reference As Range, TrackRef As Range) As Variant
  ToLastRow = Range(Reference, Reference.End(xlDown))
End Function
```

If you need to track row insertion, refer any column as the dummy argument:

```
=ToLastRow(yourRange, G:G)
```

`Application.Volatile()` is an option, but it can decrease  performance.